# Mac 10.9 Server + Windows Foundation 2012 Server + VPNing in = Is it possible?

Tags: windows-7, vpn, windows-server-2012, mac-osx-server, emulation

I need to be able to connect to both a Mac 10.9 server and a Windows Foundation 2012 Server at the same time through a single VPN login...

Alright so here's the skinny on the setup.

Running OSX Server(Day to day files). Need to install a server based Windows only software(accounting). Cannot install the Windows software onto the OSX Server (based on MS - cannot run a virtual image of a MS Server).

We have 3 MBPs (Late 2013) that are running OSX 10.9. MacMini Server to be running 10.9 & Server3.0. We will also have Windows laptops (pref run Win7) and a Dell PowerEdge to run the Windows Server for the accounting software.

Is it possible to have a single VPN connection that would allow access to both servers for the Windows PCs?

Is it possible to allow the MBPs to access both servers while in a Parellels environment? (I would assume it would be through a method like above, but would like to double ask!)

Comment: It is totally possible, even commonplace to access whole networks of machines through a single VPN connection, if the client is physical or virtual is of little consequence. But what are you intending to use as VPN Gateway?